# not able to delete row from SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a SQLite Database app following new boston video tutorials . Everything is working fine except I can't delete any row from the database or table. The app is supposed to delete a product when I enter the name of the prduct and press the delete button but when I do that, nothing happens.

Here is my Products class **(Products.java)**

```
public class Products {

    private  int _id;
    private String _productname;

    public Products() {
    }

    public Products(String _productname) {
        this._productname = _productname;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_productname(String _productname) {
        this._productname = _productname;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }
```

Handler Class **(MyDBHandler.java)**:

```
 public void deleteProduct(String productName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "=\";" );
    }

    public String databasetoString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " +  TABLE_PRODUCTS  + " WHERE 1 ";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null){
                dbString += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

**MainActivity**:

```
 public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String inputText= buckysInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputText);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databasetoString();
        buckysText.setText(dbString);
        buckysInput.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: Why  do you have this at the end of delete query? `"=\"` (equal sign)

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Where is 'buckysInput' initialized ?

Comment: Everything is initialized , I just didn't include it, to keep the length minimal @ThomasMary

Comment: no error @ScaryWombat, but its not working as expected

Comment: You should generally lean towards using statements.  Even if injection isn't a real possibility here, statements make it easy and error free to properly quote and otherwise add parameters to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be  as .

```
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "='" + productName + "'");
}
```

Comment: No, the OP should be using a prepared statement here, as injection into a `DELETE` query could be disastrous.

Comment: what do you mean @TimBiegeleisen how could it be disastrous ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen LOL  `productName = "123 OR > 1"`

Comment: @Cersie Read about SQL injection.  You absolutely should not be running a `DELETE` statement in production which is built with string concatenation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're supposing that the app is connected to internet and that there are hackers interested in wasting their time on it.

Comment: @KlingKlang Maybe not this time, but when the code works the OP maybe decide to use it in a web app